# Let $G = \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ with group law given by addition. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $(2,3)$. To which group is $G/H$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G = \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ with group law given by addition. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $(2,3)$; so $H$ consists of all elements of the form $(2a,3a)$ for some $a \in \Bbb Z$. To which group is $G/H$ isomorphic to?

My idea was to let $\varphi:G \to \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3$ be the map sending $(a,b) \longmapsto (a \pmod 2, b \pmod 3)$. The kernel is now $\ker \varphi=\{(a,b) \in \Bbb Z \mid \varphi(a,b)=(a \pmod 2, b \pmod 3)=(0,0) \}$ i.e. tuples where the first coordinate is a multiple of $2$ and the second a multiple of $3$ that is $\ker \varphi = H$.

Now $$G/\ker \varphi = G/H \cong \operatorname{im} \varphi$$

and $\operatorname{im} \varphi = \{(a \pmod 2, b \pmod 3) \mid (a,b) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z\} = \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3$ so $$G/H \cong \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3$$

However there is apparently a flaw in the reasoning here, but I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. Is $\ker \varphi = H$ an untrue statement?

Comment: Yes, it is an untrue statement, since $(2,0)$ and $(0,3)$ both lie in the kernel, but not in $H$.

Comment: $G$ is free abelian of rank $2$, $H$ is free abelian of rank $1$. The quotient cannot be a torsion group; the quotient will be the direct sum of a free abelian group of rank $1$ and a torsion group.

Comment: "i.e. tuples where the first coordinate is a multiple of $2$ and the second a multiple of $3$" yes, so for example $(2a,3b)$ belongs to the kernel. While your $H$ requires $a=b$. The kernel is bigger than your $H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The torsion group can be (and in this case is) trivial, right?

Comment: @RobertShore: Haven't worked it out in detail, but yes; the point is the rank has to be $1$, and it's a 2-generated group (which to me means it can be generated by $2$ elements, but could be generated by one).

Answer (score 6):

As we've noted, the kernel of your map is strictly larger than your $H$: your $H$ consists only of those elements in which the first entry is a multiple of $2$, and the second entry is the *same* multiple of $3$ (that is, of the form $(2m,3m)$ for a single $m$). However, the kernel consists of all elements whose first entry is any multiple of $2$ and second entry is *any* multiple of $3$, elements of the form $(2r,3s)$ with $r$ and $s$ arbitrary. So $(2,0)$ lies in the kernel, but not in $H$, for example.

Now, the group is generated by the images of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Consider the image of $(1,0)$ in $G/H$. Is this element of finite order? No: because
$$\begin{align*}
k\left( (1,0)+H\right) = (0,0)+H &\iff (k,0)+H = (0,0)+H\\
&\iff (k,0)\in H\\
&\iff \exists m\text{ such that }(k,0)=(2m,3m)\\
&\iff k=0.
\end{align*}$$
So we know for sure the quotient is not finite.
Similarly, $(0,1)$ maps to an element of infinite order.

In addition, since $(2,0)+H = (0,-3)+H$, we also know the image of $(0,1)$ has a multiple that is eventually in the image of the subgroup generated by $(1,0)$. That suggests that we might try mapping both to the same cyclic group of infinite order, in such a way that they will satisfy this relation.

So perhaps we might try the map $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $(a,b)\longmapsto 3a-2b$. It is clear that $H$ is contained in the kernel, since $(2,3)\mapsto 3(2)-2(3)=0$. It is also clear that the map is surjective, since $(1,1)\mapsto 3-2 = 1$. So then it's a matter of checking whether the kernel is *exactly* $H$, or if as you did I've inadvertedly defined a map with a larger kernel than I intended.

Comment: I was able to follow along until your last sentence. The kernel of the map $(a,b) \mapsto 3a-2b$ is precisely $H$, so I am not sure what you mean about inadvertently defining a map with a larger kernel....

Comment: @Mike I'm saying we need to check the kernel is *exactly* $H$; I only showed that $H$ is contained in the kernel. The original post defined a map whose kernel contained $H$ and was surjective, but the kernel of that map was bigger than $H$, not the desired outcome. So what I mean twas: we still need to *verify* that the kernel is **exactly** $H$ in order to conclude that $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}$. I have not done that verification.

Comment: I think the Smith normal form would work here.  Though I would have to look it up.

Comment: @Cpc It does, and you end up with, I think, $(1\ 0)$, which tells you you have the group $(\mathbb{Z}/1\mathbb{Z})\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z})$. And if you keep track of the operations, you can deduce the isomorphism.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't get $\Bbb Z$ for the quotient.   See my, albeit not that insightful,  answer (i did some googling) .  I really think that there's some torsion in the quotient.

Comment: @Cpc my map has kernel $H$: if $(a,b)$ is in the kernel, then $3a=2b$. So $b=3k$ and $a=2r$. Then $6r=6k$, so $r=k$, hence $(a,b)=(2k,3k)=k(2,3)\in H$. So my map gives an explicit isomorphism. No need to guess: your calculation is wrong and your interpretation of what you get is also is also incorrect: your values would give a torsion group. You computed for $\langle (2,0),(0,3)\rangle$, not $H$.

Comment: I see my mistake.

Comment: @Cpc I'll post a second solution using thevSmith normal form in a bit.

Comment: I just did.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

A less ad hoc way to figure out the quotient is to use the [Smith Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). The Smith Normal Form of an integer $n\times m$ matrix is an $n\times m$ matrix in which all off-diagonal entries are $0$, and the diagonal entries $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_k$ (with $k=\min(n,m)$) satisfy $\alpha_1\mid \alpha_2 \mid\cdots \mid \alpha_k$. It is obtained by doing elementary row and column operations, but where you are only allowed to add integer multiples of one row/column to another, and you may only multiply a row or column by $1$ or $-1$, and not an arbitrary nonzero scalar.

To do this, given a set of $m$ generators for a subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, write the generators as columns to get an $n\times m$ matrix. Here, our generator is $(2,3)$, so the matrix is $2\times 1$.
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}2\\3\end{array}\right).$$
Now, elementary column operations correspond to replacing the generating set of $H$ with another generating set obtained from the old one by the corresponding operations. Elementary row operations correspond to performing an invertible integral linear transformation on $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to transform the generating set of $H$ into an easier generating set for an equivalent subgroup.

First, we subtract the first row from the second row. This corresponds to the automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that sends $(1,0)$ to $(1,-1)$, and sends $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$. This will send the generator $(2,3)$ of $H$ to $(2,-2)+(0,3) = (2,1)$. So we get
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}2\\1\end{array}\right).$$
Then exchange the two rows, which corresponds to exchanging our generators; this is the automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that sends $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$. The generator $(2,1)$ of our subgroup is sent to $(1,2)$.
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\end{array}\right).$$
Now subtract twice the first row form the second row. This is the automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that sends $(1,0)$ to $(1,-2)$ and sends $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$. It sends $(1,2)$ to $(1,0)$. So we get the matrix in Smith Normal Form,
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right).$$
Now it is easy to just read off what the quotient is: what is the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by the subgroup generated by $(1,0)$? It is $\mathbb{Z}$. So the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

You can obtain an explicit morphism by keeping track of the operations. The elementary matrices that yield the elementary row operations I performed give
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0\\
-2 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{rr}1&0\\-1&0\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 1\\
3 & -2\end{array}\right).$$
Thus, we want the map that sends $(1,0)$ to $(-1,3)$ and sends $(0,1)$ to $(1,-2)$; this map sends $(2,3)$ to $(-2,6)+(3,-6) = (1,0)$, and the morphism onto $\mathbb{Z}$ with that kernel is given by projection along the second component. So we want the map
$$(a,b)\to \pi_2\Bigl( a(-1,3)+b(1,-2)\Bigr) = \pi_2(-a+b,3a-2b) = 3a-2b,$$
which is the map I suggested in my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix in Smith normal form is $$\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 3\end {pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 3\end {pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 0\end {pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end {pmatrix}$$.

I get that the so-called *invariant factor* is then $1$.

Thus we get $\Bbb Z$ for the quotient.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. Usually, for an $m$-generated subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ you get an $n\times m$ matrix, so you should have a $2\times 1$ matrix, not a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks.  @ArturoMagidin

Comment: In Smith normal form, the off-diagonal entries should be zero, and the diagonal entries should each divide the next one. Your result is not in Smith Normal Form.

Comment: Oops.   I'll learn Smith normal form from you one way or another.   Many thanks.   @ArturoMagidin

Comment: There are a number of posts in the site that go through the algorithm.

Comment: Yeah,  I think I know the rules.   But that was a blunder.  @ArturoMagidin